# missing package in Coldfusion 9 using JavaLoader

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, javaloader

I have ColdFusion 9.0.2 and Java 1.6.0_29.  I'm trying to use the [java loader](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader) project to compile java code but I am receiving this error.

```
package javax.servlet.http does not exist import
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
```

However, the javax.servlet.http package seems to be there already b/c I can execute this code without error:

```
<cfset obj = createObject("java","javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest")>
<cfdump var="#obj#">
```

I've tried [downloading the jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5) for javax.servlet.http and adding it to CF (paste in C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib and restart cf service) but it doesn't make any difference.  Is an older version of this package included in a jar that is part of CF or something?

Comment: Are you getting that error when compiling custom sources or when you run the basic [HelloWorld example](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader/tree/develop/example/compileHelloWorld)? Can you post the full stack trace? *RE: ...the javax.servlet.http package seems to be there already* Yes, ColdFusion is a servlet. So it is included in the main CF class path. However, the JavaLoader does not include the main CF class path path by default. Try setting  `loadColdFusionClassPath=true`.

Comment: Thanks, Leigh!  Adding loadColdFusionClassPath=true fixed it... or at least got me past that dependency error :-)

Comment: *at least got me past that dependency error* Ahh, the joys of resolving dependencies ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. ColdFusion itself runs as a servlet (essentially). So the javax.servlet library is already included in the main CF class path, which is why the `createObject()` call works.  However, the [JavaLoader does not load the CF class path by default](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader/wiki/Class-Loading).

> **Parameter:** loadColdFusionClassPath
>
> **Defaults to:** `false`
>
> Loads the ColdFusion libraries with the loaded
>   libraries. This used to be on by default, however now you must
>   implicitly set it to be `true` if you wish to access any of the
>   libraries that ColdFusion loads at application start up.

Try setting `loadColdFusionClassPath = true`. Adding the javax.servlet jar file to the `loadPaths` array may work as well.